# VLC can't play videos in different partition (Ubuntu 17.10)

Tags: video, vlc, snap, flatpak

I recently installed VLC 3 on Ubuntu 17.10 using snaps and I am unable to play videos which are stored on different partition. Videos stored on same partition as ubuntu works fine.
Also previously I used VLC on same laptop but used pre-installed version it was 2.2.something and it worked fine.
Is this a problem with snaps? If so will Flatpak work fine?

Comment: Have you tried other media players? Do they work fine?

Comment: Snaps are confined to the user home directory by designe. You should try flatpack to find out.

Comment: Other media player (of snaps) don't work, and flatpak works.@Sadegh Ghasemi